# phpBB SEO memberlist pagination error caused by Ultimate SEO URL plugin

Tags: pagination, seo, phpbb

I have recently installed following mods on my PhpBB board (version 3.0.12):

- Zero Dupe
- Ultimate SEO URL
- Related Links
- Gym Sitemap

The problem is that the pagination for `memberlist.php` is broken now.

Instead of giving me a link that looks like `forumRoot/memberlist.php?start=25` for page 2; I get `forumRoot/?start=25`.

I have tried looking on an official forum but it did not help me at all since even mods of the plugin sometimes unsure how to deal with it.

Comment: This forum thread looks relevant: http://www.phpbb-seo.com/en/phpbb-seo-premod/article6197.html

Comment: I did check this thread, but the main catch is that it only discuss a bug in pre-mod version of PHP BB, when I have had a clean one and then installed mods. Thank you for your answer anyway :)

Comment: Can you try disabling the plugins one at a time to determine which one is responsible?   My bet is on the Ultimate SEO URL plugin.

Comment: I did disable the SEO URL and then my pagination came back to normal, thanks. But still I do need to use the plugin for url rewrite. Any recommendations?